# Object doesn't take value

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, null, int

I am sorry about the title of this post, but I've no idea how to describe my problem.

So, I've got the following really simple code:

```
dynamic obj = new myClass(); // In my case it is a COM object
int FileCount = 0;
FileCount = obj.SomeMethod();
```

But at runtime I get something like this:
[image]

Whats going on there? Why isn't `Filecount = 0`? Why is it null?

Comment: That looks like a runtime watch. So the code does compile? (Note it doesn't say `FileCount` is null, but that it doesn't exist.) Are you running in the Debug mode?

Comment: obj.SomeMethod() - what does this method return ? integer?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the refresh button on the right of the watch window (last thing in the value column)?

Comment: if you try to set a breakpoint to the line "int FileCount = 0" does the breakpoint get hit? I think you are getting problem with temporary file. Try to remove it from Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/yourversion/Temporary ASP.NET File...

Comment: Yes it does compile. The screen-shot was made while debugging, so of course it is Debug mode ;)
And SomeMethod does return integer. But, SomeMethod havent been execute when I took the screen-shot.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can run a release build in the debugger strangely enough but you get a warning by default.

Comment: @MattSpinelli Already done ;), nothing happens

Comment: @2GDev Like you said the breakpoint doesn't hit, the red marker don't stay at line 82, it always jumps to 83 when I start debugging.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Yor're right, when switching into Debug mode in top of VS, everything just work fine! But whats the problem with the Release mode? Will it break when I release the App?

Comment: It sounds like you're not reading from the variable yet and it's being optimised away? Read from the variable even if you just write it to the console for now and it should work in release build?

Comment: btw... in the code from the screenshot you have `dynamic obj = new object();` instead of `new myClass();`. This code should result in a RuntimeBinderException as object does not have a SomeMethod(). I guess this is just a simplified version of your code to show your problem, but I wanted to make you aware just in case...

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in Release build?. If FileCount is not used somewhere else the variable might be optimized out by the compiler. Try doing that in Debug build. Also this can be caused by pdb files mismatch. Clean all your output dirs and recompile the application.

Answer (score 0):

Optimised out I should think, the initialisation is certainly pointless

int FileCount = obj.SomeMethod();

Because it's dynamic all sorts of compiler magic happen to evade errors, daresay this one is down to all the code that gets whapped in behind the scenes to deal with obj being dynamic.