# Can't see variables while debugging

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I had the weirdest problem happen this morning. I'm stepping through the code and some of the variables are not accessible in the debugger:

[image: Debugging]

As you can see above a & b are not accessible by the debugger while the 'TrsApp' variable is. I have the dll i'm debugging highlighted in the module window so you can see the pdb was loaded correctly and isn't optimized.

I've tried to rebuild everything of course and still i have the issue.

I have a fully updated Win 7 x64 machine. Visual Studio has Update 1 applied. This project is using .Net Framework 4.0

Update: I really thought it was something messed up with my machine so i sent the solution to a fellow developer. Well same results. He couldn't see the variables. So far it appears anything variables defined in the function i'm stepping through aren't visible. All variables i've defined externally so far seem visible.

Update 2: I think it might have something to do with the fact that we are loading the dll by reflection. Not sure why it would matter but this is really the only difference between this assemblies and the others. You will notice in the module window that the directory is different.

Comment: does hovering over the variables show any values? also are you watch variables from the same function?

Comment: Are you in [release mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065735/object-doesnt-take-value)? (I know its another error, give it a try anyway)

Comment: @Amitd Nope hovering doesn't show anything either.

Comment: @GameScripting: Definitely built in debug you can tell above since the dll isn't optimized.

Comment: Is the code file from the same solution? What happens when you debug line by line .. F10/F11 from start of function?

Comment: @Amitd: I tried stepping line by line through the function referenced above and still the same results. Yes the code i'm stepping through is in the solution (there are also 2 other projects).

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with VS 2017 15.5.6. I have optimization turned off in debug mode, yet when I reflect on the code I see local variables still optimized away, and interim variables used (ex: asyncVariable0, asyncVariable1).